# Primary Decomposition of $ k\times k$ Permanents of a $m\times n$ Matrix

Tags: commutative-algebra, permanent

Let $I$ be the ideal in $\displaystyle\,k\left[x_{1,1}, \ldots, x_{m,n}\right]$ generated by the $k\times k$ permanents of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1,1} & \cdots & x_{1,n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
x_{m,1} & \cdots & x_{m,n}\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

What is a primary decomposition of $I$?

I have figured out that in the $2 \times n$ case, the primary components are the vanishing of the top row, the vanishing of the bottom row, and then one permanent vanishes and all other variables vanish. In total, this is ${n \choose 2}+2$ primary components.

Related:
[Primary Decomposition of $ 2\times 2$ Permanents of a $2\times 3$ Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199158/primary-decomposition-of-2-times-2-permanents-of-a-2-times-3-matrix)